# PHP textbox box empty

Tags: php, html, error-handling, is-empty

> I has read all the various post on StackOverflow regards this same but that was not helpful ...

Php script not shows error alert when text box empty or in invalid pattern. I know only empty script which I mention below but I don't known How I add pattern error also.

Also when textbox empty it not show error why? Please help. Please don't mark as it is duplicate because I read various post but same issue that is why I posted a threads. Please help in full script.

Advance thank you..

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 $name= $_POST['name'];
 if (!($name))
 {
 $m1 = "<Div class="alert">Enter your Name</Div>" ;
 }

 $email= $_POST['email'];
 if (!($email))
 {
 $m2 = "<Div class="alert">Enter Your Email"</Div> ;
 }

 $_SESSION['name'] =$name;
 $_SESSION['email'] =$email;
 $_SESSION['otp']=$rndno;
 header( "Location: next-page.php" ); 
} 
?>
```

**In HTML Body**

```
<div>
<?php if(isset($m1)) { echo $m1; } ?>
<?php if(isset($m2)) { echo $m2; } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You have some unescaped double-quotes in your strings. Try using single-quotes for the strings, eg `$m1 = '<Div class="alert">Enter your Name</Div>';`, etc

Comment: Control your variables; `if ($email != "") { // do something } else { echo "error"; }`

Comment: After `$email= $_POST['email'];` or before?

Comment: Set your variables at top of all `if` conditions

Comment: Check your lines defining `$m1` and `$m2`, they're both faulty. Also comment out the line `header( "Location: next-page.php" );` to see your code in action, otherwise you'll always be redirected to `next-page.php` when you submit

Comment: In `action="no-url"`  did your Means `$m1 & $m2` is error? If yes, What is Correct?

Comment: There is no `action="no-url"` in your code above. @Phil's comment basically

Comment: Please view this my php codes. I am using  https://pastebin.com/2gBkLatk .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code it is runnable

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 $name= $_POST['name'];
 if ( $name == '')
 {
 echo $m1 = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please Enter Your Name');</script>" ;
 }

 $email= $_POST['email'];
 elseif ( $email == '')
 {
 echo $m2 = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Enter Your E-mail');</script>" ;
 }

 $_SESSION['name'] =$name;
 $_SESSION['email'] =$email;
 $_SESSION['otp']=$rndno;
else{
 header( "Location: next-page.php" ); 
}
}

?>
```

Comment: I am using Div instead alert. Can I use single inverted comma (')

Comment: Yes using single inverted comma ('alert') because already use the double inverted comma to make string. so we not use that

Comment: Yes, you can use ( ' ), whenever you're writing something enclosed in double quotes use single quotes (or vice-versa) to make it a proper string

Comment: Same issue, without any error it's jump on next page. Can share my all php script? It's help you to understand easy.